# Resize an image in an email using typed percentages instead of drag bars in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I frequently take large images and jam them into emails, but when I do, they always paste gigantic.

Is there a text-based / keyboard-shortcut / non-click and drag way to do this in Outlook?

I do not wish to change the actual resolution of the image; only to resize it in the email; even if by percentage / stylesheet (the Responsive Web Design way) that resizes based on the size of the Window.

Answer (score -1):

In Outlook itself? No.

As an [Office Outlook Add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)? I [looked](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?page=1&src=office&product=office%3Boutlook) but did not find one.

--

There are Open Source CLI tools which will check a file's dimensions, such as `exiftool %1  | find /I "X Resolution"` (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/exiftool/).

There are Open Source CLI tools to resize a file to a desired width (e.g., 800 pixels) while maintaining the original aspect ratio such as `convert %1 -resize 800 _%1` (See https://imagemagick.org).

These could be scripted; you could use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to start a script to

- open a Command Prompt window in a desired directory (like Pictures?)
- check a given file and
- resize it if if exceeds a desired size, then
- close the Command Prompt window.

Then, back in Outlook, add the resized file (in the example above, its name would start with the underscore and be followed by the original file name) into your email instead of the original.

Comment: ‘imagemagick’ is malware is it not?

Comment: Also, I don’t want to change the resolution only the size it appears in the email;  I’d even settle for some kind of style sheet that does Responsive Web Design inside the email the dynamically resizes it based on the size of the Window.

Comment: Imagemagick is reliable Open Source, has been for many years. If you get it from GitHub or the Publisher, it's reliable. Getting it from a 'freeware' site is dicey.  Whomever suggested it is malware has Low Reality Perception.

Comment: If your intent is to preserve the file size while shrinking only its appearance within the body text, I'd suggest rephrasing your question to state that. Your subject line specified "Resize an image..." which is what my answer does.

Comment: Done; thank you.